# Weird shading on a sharp object

Tags: modeling, shaders, edges

I'm trying to make an object that would keep some of the edges sharp, but it's causing a weird shading on the corners. How do I fix that, if I want to keep the bottom, the top and the side sharp (they're all marked).

I'm using the bevel modifier with limit method selected as weight. I tried to increase the segment count, recalculate normals. When I put a ngon here the problem got solved though. How do I fix that if I don't want any ngons in the mesh?

Thanks![image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try using "Harden Normals" in the Bevel Modifier, or in the Object Properties Tab under "Normals" the "Auto Smooth" option?

Comment: Oops, tried auto smooth but not in combination with harden normals - fixed, thanks!